# SOLR multiple facet w query

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I need to facet sorl based on multiple categories, 3 categorise to be exact. The issue I have is I need different to facet what are essentially seperate queries, but i'm trying to determine if I can do it with one. In essense I'd like to do a filter.query but instead of the count, i'd like to get the values of the matches.

the problem is im matchign against multiple fields for the same value, lets say 
`field1=*bah* OR field2=*bah* or field3=*bah*` and I facet on field1,field2, and field3

The query does return those docs who's field match, but on the facet, for field1, doesnt include only matchign field1 bah.. but includes the docs who matched field2 and field3, who's field1 value was not *bah*.

id basically like to use fq={!tag} with facet.field{!ex} to produce facets of field1 with only field1 matching values, facet 2 withoutly field2 matchign value.. and so on.

Is this even possible with one query in solr?

Here is my basic setup

```
<document>
  <field1>bah boo</field1>
  <field2>bah bing</field2>
  <field3>boo bar</field3>
</document>
<document>
  <field1>bar boo</field1>
  <field2>bah bong</field2>
  <field3>bah bar</field3>
</document>
<document>
  <field1>bar boo</field1>
  <field2>ding bah</field2>
  <field3>bog bar</field3>
</document>
<document>
  <field1>ban bah</field1>
  <field2>ban bing</field2>
  <field3>bbah bar</field3>
</document>
```

and i'd like to return

```
<facets>
   <field1>
     <str>bah boo</str>
     <str>ban bah</str>
   </field1>
   <field2>
     <str>bah bing</str>
     <str>bah bong</str>
     <str>ding bah</str>
   </field2>
   <field3>
     <str>bah bar</str>
     <str>bbah bar</str>
   </field3>
</facets>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include highlighting along with faceting, your actual matches will be returned in the `highlighting` structure. It won't give you the **number** of matches, however, and it will only give the matches for the rows returned by your query. Actually, I'm not sure that you need to use faceting at all for what you're trying to do here.

I could be wrong, but your question sounds similar to this one:
[How to return column that matched the query in Solr..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629147/how-to-return-column-that-matched-the-query-in-solr/)

Hope this helps.