# How to return column that matched the query in Solr..?

Tags: database, solr

I am using apache Solr for searching my database..!!

Suppose i have indexed 4 columns from one of my table..!!..I just want that only those columns ***that contains my query term*** are returned in response..!!..is that possible..??

For example :

I have a table **cars** with columns : ***name, displayName, description, extra*** ..!!

Now i make a query , something like :

```
localhost:8983/solr/select?q=maruti&wt=json
```

Now some in some rows only ***name***  may contain the word "*maruti*"

So, In return, i want only **name** (along with some other fixed fields like **ID**) ..

Similarly, If ***description*** contains this word, then only ***description*** should be returned..and not other columns..!!

How can i acheive this..??

Comment: Why did this question got a downvote..??..Please be specific..!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be able to do this with Solr 4 and a custom transformer - my reading of the documentation would seem to indicate as much. But it would be quite a bit of work, I think. Ultimately you may have to write a front-end filter, but that would be difficult with complex queries.

**Update**:
Here's how to do this in Solr without custom transformers, etc. Enable highlighting for all four columns:

```
hl=on&hl.fl=name,displayName,description,extra
```

Solr will return a "highlighting" structure containing the key and the field(s) that match the query. You will also get highlighted snippets, whether you use them is up to you. See here for additional params: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters

Comment: Yeah..i was thinking of writing front-end filter...neways thanx for the reply...i'll see what to do..!!

Comment: @RamandeepSingh, please see my updated answer. I think it answers your question!

Comment: This requires all 4 columns to be stored. What if I have 100 columns?

Comment: @TerenceYeong, I am not quite sure what your question is. Is storing 100 fields an issue for you? Or are you worried about the `hl.fl` parameter? It can accept wildcards.

Comment: Hi David, I was concerned about the cons of storing 100 fields, specifically hdd space and searching performance.

Comment: @TerenceYeong, I am not sure I could comment without knowing the particulars of your situation. Solr doesn't have a limit on the number of fields allowed - the limit depends on your hardware etc. You could probably simplify your schema.xml file by using dynamic fields.