# Replacing SOLR output field value

Tags: solr

I have below mentioned SOLR query which works fine.

*query*:"COMPLEX CONDITION 1" OR *query*:"COMPLEX CONDITION 2"

I get 4  documents in result - 2 from condition1 and 2 from condition2. I need to know  documents belong to which condition.
I cannot figure out from the result as the conditions are too complex.
What i want to do is change the value of the "status" field in the output.
Lets say, status=Active for condition1 and status=Expired for condition2.

The current value of status is not accurate as the status is decided based on the conditions i use.

Is there a way to overwrite the output value of any field(s) in SOLR?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using highlighting to determine which documents matched which condition? If you turn on highlighting (`&hl=on&hl.fl=<fields_you're_trying_to_match>`), then Solr will return a structure at the end of the results structure (whether you're returning results in JSON or XML) called "highlighting." This structure in turn will contain structures named according to the unique key of your index (if there is one) with elements that match.

```
<lst name="highlighting">
    <lst name="1">
        <arr name="title">
            <str>Bob <em>Jones</em></str>
        </arr>
        <arr name="category">
            <str><em>Jones</em> Family</str>
        </arr>
        <arr name="description">
            <str>This is a book about Bob <em>Jones</em>, the patriarch of the <em>Jones</em> Family.</str>
        </arr>
    <lst>
<lst>
```

More here:
[How to return column that matched the query in Solr..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629147/how-to-return-column-that-matched-the-query-in-solr)

Now I apologize that this doesn't answer the latter part of your question, but gives you some help for the first part.