# Full-Text Determine matched field

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a table setup with a full-text index on ID, StreetNumber, StreetName, StreetType for a live form search.  Sample data would look like:

```
       ID        StreetNumber   StreetName   StreetType
   -----------------------------------------------------
   | 141099  |        1411   |  Elm       |      ST    |
   -----------------------------------------------------
   | 141100  |        2901   |  Maple     |      LN    |
   -----------------------------------------------------
```

If I query using:

```
SELECT ID, StreetName, StreetNumber, StreetType
FROM Locations
WHERE MATCH(ID, StreetName, StreetNumber, StreetType)
      AGAINST('1411*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

It will return both records of course...  However, I'm having trouble finding an easy way to determine what field it matched on.

I would like to format my live search results to something like:

```
ID: 141100 (2901 Maple Lane)
Address: 1411 Elm St
```

...sorted by what they matched on.  Formatting in PHP is easy, it's finding what the results matched on is the problem.  However, I can't find a way to do this without having to examine it in PHP (not very efficient).  Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the search efficiently with a fulltext index, and then use another solution to test the columns the select-list (which runs only against rows that pass the filter in the WHERE clause):

```
SELECT ID, StreetName, StreetNumber, StreetType,
  (StreetName like '%1411%') AS `StreetName_matches`, 
  (StreetNumber like '%1411%') AS `StreetNumber_matches`,
  (StreetType like '%1411%') AS `StreetType_matches`
FROM Locations 
WHERE MATCH(ID, StreetName, StreetNumber, StreetType) 
      AGAINST('1411*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Or you could create four individual fulltext indexes on the columns, and search each of them in turn:

```
SELECT ID, StreetName, StreetNumber, StreetType,
  MAX(`ID_Matches`) AS `ID_Matches`,
  MAX(`StreetName_Matches`) AS `StreetName_Matches`,
  MAX(`StreetNumber_Matches`) AS `StreetNumber_Matches`,
  MAX(`StreetType_Matches`) AS `StreetType_Matches`
FROM (
  SELECT SELECT ID, StreetName, StreetNumber, StreetType,
    1 AS `ID_Matches`,
    NULL AS `StreetName_Matches`,
    NULL AS `StreetNumber_Matches`,
    NULL AS `StreetType_Matches`
  FROM Locations 
  WHERE MATCH(ID) AGAINST('1411*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SELECT ID, StreetName, StreetNumber, StreetType,
    NULL AS `ID_Matches`,
    1 AS `StreetName_Matches`,
    NULL AS `StreetNumber_Matches`,
    NULL AS `StreetType_Matches`,
  FROM Locations 
  WHERE MATCH(StreetName) AGAINST('1411*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SELECT ID, StreetName, StreetNumber, StreetType,
    NULL AS `ID_Matches`,
    NULL AS `StreetName_Matches`,
    1 AS `StreetNumber_Matches`,
    NULL AS `StreetType_Matches`,
  FROM Locations 
  WHERE MATCH(StreetNumber) AGAINST('1411*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SELECT ID, StreetName, StreetNumber, StreetType,
    NULL AS `ID_Matches`,
    NULL AS `StreetName_Matches`,
    NULL AS `StreetNumber_Matches`,
    1 AS `StreetType_Matches`,
  FROM Locations 
  WHERE MATCH(StreetTYPE) AGAINST('1411*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) AS t
GROUP BY t.ID;
```

You may also want to look into a more fully-featured full text search technology, like [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com) or [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

See for example the answer to [How to return column that matched the query in Solr..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629147/how-to-return-column-that-matched-the-query-in-solr)

Comment: The first solution works well and is pretty simple to implement.  The second solution seems like it may offer a little more work, but perhaps more flexible (I could return counts as well). It could be streamlined to instead use one column `0 as MatchType`,`1 as MatchType`  to later be checked via switch(). I'm unsure of the impact of 4 indexes would be vs 1 index on a table with 13k records and 80 columns (yes, I am very well versed in normalization).  Great answer, thanks for the assistance!

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the impact of four indexes versus one index for that table.  What you want is for indexes to stay in memory, in this case the MyISAM key cache.  Start worrying when your data grows large enough so that the indexes have to load from disk during a query.