# If I match a text string against multiple columns, is there an easy way to know which one(s) matched?

Tags: sql, matching

I'm writing an advanced search functionality that returns records where a string matches one or more out of many text columns in this table.

Something like:

```
select * from some_table where (txt_1 like '%foo%') or (txt_2 like '%foo%') or...
```

Or:

```
select * from some_table where match (txt_1, txt_2, ...) against ('foo')
```

if I can do full-text search (not sure yet).

My issue is, how can I know which columns actually matched 'foo'?

For instance, if I have these records:

```
id  txt_1  txt_2  txt_3  txt_4
1   'foo'  'bar'  'bar'  'foo'
2   'bar'  'bar'  'bar'  'bar'
3   'bar'  'foo'  'bar'  'bar'
4   'bar'  'bar'  'bar'  'bar'
```

my query should return something like:

```
id  txt_1_matches  txt_2_matches  txt_3_matches  txt_4_matches
1   1              0              0              1
3   0              1              0              0
```

I can do this with post-processing on the simple query results, but I'd like to avoid it.
Is there a clean, easy way to do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the search efficiently with a fulltext index, and then apply your first solution in the select-list (which runs only against rows that pass the filter in the WHERE clause):

```
select (txt_1 like '%foo%') as `txt1_matches`, 
       (txt_2 like '%foo%') as `txt2_matches`, ...
from some_table where match (txt_1, txt_2, ...) against ('foo')
```

You may also want to look into a more fully-featured full text search technology, like [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com) or [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

See for example the answer to [How to return column that matched the query in Solr..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629147/how-to-return-column-that-matched-the-query-in-solr)

Comment: Yup that should do it thanks :) I was hoping to avoid that kind of syntax because I'm matching against 20 columns or so, but I'll just have to live with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT id,
          txt_1 LIKE '%foo%' AS a,
          txt_2 LIKE '%foo%' AS b,
          txt_3 LIKE '%foo%' AS c,
          txt_4 LIKE '%foo%' AS d
   FROM some_table) AS q
WHERE a OR b OR c OR d;
```

Notice I put it in a subquery.  I need to do this in MySQL or it complains that column 'a' doesn't exist, etc...

Comment: Thanks, this is a variation on the solution above, so I guess this is what I'll have to do :)