# Solr edismax. How to retrieve the fields that gave the query result

Tags: solr, edismax

I'm querying mulitple fields using the qf param. But I'm wondering how I can retrieve the field that gave the result.

Example(not a real example):

```
      q={!edismax qf='tag content'}("tablet")AND("pc")
```

Field values:

```
      doc1:
           tag: tablet
           content: The test has failled. Use a pc instead.
      doc2:
           tag: tablet pc
           content: The test has worked.
```

As a result both documents will be returned because they both have the tablet and pc in their tag/content. ***Is it possible to know that doc2 had both hits in tag and doc1 only had 1 hit in tag and 1 in content?*** Debugquery doesn't seem to provide information about this.

I know I can increase the importance of a searchfield using the qf boost.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? It helps if you can let us know what you are trying to do with such results.

Comment: To let the user know whether the result was found from the content of a file or from a user added tag.

Answer (score 1):

you can either:

1. use [Highlighting](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Highlighting)
2. ask for debug info with debugQuery=true and parse the scoring info to find out.

I think 1 is easier, but it imposes some constraints on your fields (they must be stored for example)

Comment: My fields are stored so thats not a problem. I didn't know highlighting returned the field it hit. I'll try to find out whether this works.

Comment: I'd also say, try highlighting. This was also the answer to the similar question [How to return column that matched the query in Solr..?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629147/how-to-return-column-that-matched-the-query-in-solr)

Answer (score 0):

Ok based on your response to my question.

Unfortunately, there is no way Solr currently returns which fields matched the query as part of your defaulting result docs . If the query is simple, looping over the returned stored fields is  probably your best bet. Highlighting  is be an option too.

There are couple of other options suggested here : `http://grokbase.com/t/lucene/solr-user/117nkf36nq/determine-which-field-term-was-found`